# How can one easily toggle iOS so that ALL sounds (including alarms) are silenced for a set time period or until the toggle is reversed?

Tags: alarm, sound-volume, ios, do-not-disturb

With the introduction of iOS 15 and focus mode, I have once again wished that I could find a simple way (on a standard, non-jailbroken iPhone) to temporarily silence all sounds, including alarms, for some period of time.

The main use case here, is that I have a lot of daily alarms that are always set, but some times, I am at the theater or in a special meeting, where I do not want them to go off. Turning the alarms off and on, or giving them a silent ringtone, is not really a viable option.

I'd love a control panel switch or focus mode setting that could handle this, if there was one. A fancy shortcut automation might be an option, but I'm guessing that it would still be a bit difficult to make generic enough and reliable.

Using a non-Apple app for Alarms, might be one possible approach, as I think that would be silenced, but that solution isn't ideal since most of my workflow relies on the built in alarm functionality at the moment.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this (now or in the future)?

***EDIT***: Although the list of active, recurring alarms does not change all the time, it does change frequently enough, that I'd prefer a solution that could silence all enabled alarms and then un-silence that same list without needing to maintain the list, simply because it will be error prone.

As much as I like Apple products in general, the lack of a real "theater" silent mode in 2021 is completely baffling.

Comment: I was under the impression that focus modes have the option of silencing alarms?

Comment: The only way I can think of is to shut the thing down and turn it back on afterward.

Answer (score 0):

Using shortcuts is a manageable way of doing it. You can use the "toggle alarm" shortcut to activate and deactivate your alarms and the get all alarms to provide all your alarms to the toggle. If you only want a subset of your alarms toggled then this [shortcut](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/1d841304ecb149c78ed67ed6a5dba7b6) will toggle the alarms based on the alarms' names specified in a list.

Comment: This should indeed work in the situations where the alarms that I want enabled are very stable.

Ideally though, the solution would simply silence all enabled alarms until toggled again. In the case of a shortcut, I'd prefer it could silence all enabled alarms and then un-silence that same list without needing to maintain the list, simply because it will be error prone.